# Chaining `if` and `url` template tags

Tags: python, django, django-templates, templatetags

I have a django page which contains a login form in the navbar (for quick login from the homepage) and a separate login page (to which the user is redirected if he mistypes).

My template structure is such that I have a `base.html` template and a `navbar.html` template. All of my pages extend the `base.html` template (after all, that's what it's there for, right?), and most (but not all) pages then include the `navbar.html` template inside. The code I paste below is from the `navbar` template.

I know this could be done more elegantly, but the question I have is more general, this is just a use case. What I want to do is, in the navbar, to only show the login form if the site shown at the moment is not the login site. Currently, I have

```
{% if not 'accounts/login' in request.get_full_path %}
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="{% url 'auth_login' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Log in</button>
</form>
{% endif %}
```

Which works fine. However, I don't like the fact that the `'accounts/login'` is hardcoded. Usually, I was taught that it was best practice to use the `{% url 'auth_login %}` to get the `'accounts/login'` string as this allows the string to still be correct even if I change the URLConf. However, I cannot simply write

```
{% if url 'auth_login' in request.get_full_path %}
```

What I imagine would be best is to somehow set a context variable to the value of `{% url 'auth_login' %}`, but how could this be done as cleanly as possible?

Comment: @Sayse I edited my question (see paragraph 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your base form you can just add a block to your navigation that allows for a page to have extra navigation items

```
 {% block extra_nav %}{% endblock %}
```

then inside your login page you can include the login form

```
 {% block extra_nav %}{% include 'login_form' %}{% endblock %}
```

Although this can get messy quickly.

Alternatively, you include an extra data parameter that you only ever pass in the pages that need to show it

```
 { 'show_login': True }


{% if show_login %}
     ... your form
{% endif %}
```

Since this will equate to false if not present, it will not be shown in areas where its not included

Comment: I don't understand the first solution. The base knows nothing about the navbar, since the navbar is included by the pages that extend the base, how can this work?

Comment: @5xum - Ah apologies, it will only work in places where the nav bar is in the base page, I much prefer the second approach anyway personally

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your help!